# How to condense this boilerplate into a BigQuery function

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to see if a `list` field has any elements in a list that I provide. (In other words, set-intersection.)

Here is an example of what I have now:

```
with tbl as (
  select 1 as id, ['yellow', 'red', 'green'] as colors union all
  select 2, ['yellow', 'blue']
) 
select * from tbl where 
-- hasAny(colors, ['red', 'green', 'magenta'])
WHERE 'red' IN unnest(colors) OR 'green' in unnest(colors) OR 'magenta' in unnest(colors) -- etc...
```

What would be a function to do this? And I suppose we could also change this to `hasAll` if we switched the `OR` to an `AND`. And `hasNone` if we did `NOT hasAny(needle_list, haystack_list)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be better way but I would try it with `set` operations.

- [INERSECT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#intersect_example)
- [EXCEPT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#except_example)

```
-- hasAll
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(['red', 'green', 'magneta']) 
  EXCEPT DISTINCT
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(colors)
)

-- hasAny
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(['red', 'green', 'magneta']) 
  INTERSECT DISTINCT
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(colors)
)
```

Comment: oh that's super neat, thanks for that. I didn't even think to use the sql set operations like that. Very cool!